# How can I find time difference between string date and now with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, difference

Hey guys I hope that you can help.
I have a Date string formated like '10/02/22 21:59'
Trying to find the time difference between NOW and some time in the future(string).
Tried the code below, but the result is not accurate, some 234 days off when the time difference should be juts 5 hours...
What am I doing wrong?

```js
console.log( (Date.parse('10/02/22 20:59') - Date.now()) / (1000*3600*24) )
```

234.12668752314815

Comment: You'd probably need to convert from wonky US date format to universal (or vice versa).

Comment: That is October 2nd, 2022. Not Feb 10.

Comment: See also [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)